# Align an icon vertically in jqGrid pager

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I have place a 24x24 png into the left pager of the jqgrid using the jquery code below. Also I'm applying vertical-align middle.

```
  $("#pager_left").append (
    '<td><div><img alt="" id="imgprint" src="images/word24x24.png"/></div></td>');
  $("#imgprint").css('vertical-align', 'middle');
```

The resulting html code captured from chrome developer tools is

[image]

The computed pager_left size is 214x28 + 1px padding above and below.
The resulting pager_left is shown below where the icon is aligned at bottom and not in the middle. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Just some guesses, I'd remove the `<div>` wrapping the image and put the vertical align on the `<td>`. And be sure your icon image is cropped correctly.

Comment: @Ted I removed the div with no luck. Icon is 24x24 with 0 `padding` and `border`. The `<td>` has `vertical-align:middle`, size 24x24 and padding 1.

Comment: Is there any way you can reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Did you try `vertical-align: top`? Looks like some inheritance is occurring.

Comment: It's very important to know which fork of jqGrid and in which version you use. The CSS is different in different versions. You can need to add `float:left` , `display:inline-block` or other depend of the jqGrid fork or version. Moreover one calls typically `navGrid` first to create *standard* icons and then one calls `navButtonAdd` to add custom button. To create empty navigator bar one can use `$("#grid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager",{ edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false, search: false });` Then one can add icon to the navbar. One will need set additional CSS properties on `div`

Comment: @Oleg I'm using jqGrid 4.6.0.

Comment: @fauverism I used all the vertical-align options but the icon remains stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the pager is table oriented and very hard coded in jqGrid 4.6. The setting `vertical-align` will be not really help you because it's inside of deep hierarchy of other dives and cells which will be *not* vertically centered and some from there have fixed coded `height` in pixel.

First of all I would suggest you additionally to add *empty* navigator bar to be more confirm with the existing structure of the pager.

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", 
    { edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false, search: false });
```

After that I would recommend you to define `wordIcon` class with the following CSS rules

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager { height: auto; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table { padding: 0 0 0 1px; }
.ui-pg-div .wordIcon {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-image: url("images/word24x24.png")
}
```

and use the code like

```js
$grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager", {
    buttonicon: "wordIcon",
    caption: "",
    id: 
    title: "Export to Word",
    onClickButton: function(){
        alert("Export to Word is clicked!");
    }
});
```

The above code will work good event if you would add some standard icons (Reload Grid button for example) to the navigator bar. You will have the results like on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/addPagerIcon24x24.htm)

[image]

Alternatively you can don't use `navButtonAdd` and hold your original code

```js
$("#pager_left").append (
                '<div><img alt="" id="imgprint" src="http://ephtracking.cdc.gov/images/content/word-24x24.png"/></div>');
```

with the following CSS rules:

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager { height: auto; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table { padding: 2px 0 0 1px; }
```

You will have the results like on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/addPagerIcon24x24_.htm):

[image]

Comment: I was unable to load the icon via css in the first method, probably it has to do with the application structure, so I can't say if it works for me or not. The second method moved the icon downwards instead of upwards as it should. I tried to alter the paddings with no result. The solution was given by what you said in your first paragraph Oleg. I downloaded jqGrid 4.8.2 and the icon was placed were I want it without even using vertical align or any css.